# remove button from CGridView with condition

Tags: yii, cgridview

Hi I have CRUD generated CGridView in yii. I need to add a new button to CGridView rows and hide it if **appointment_status**(one of CGridView column) value equals 0

This is my code of CGridView,

```
$this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'bookings-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'telephone',
        'time',
        'employee',       
        'appointment_status',
        'client_ip',
        'link' => array(
            'header' => 'Confirmation',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => 'CHtml::button("$data->appointment_status",array("onclick"=>"document.location.href=\'".Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("controller/action",array("id"=>$data->id))."\'"))',
            'visible'=>$data->appointment_status==1,
        ),
        array(
            'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
        ),
    ),
));
```

But all I'm getting is error stating,

> Undefined variable: data

It would be great help if someone can look into it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your 'visible' handling the column visibility and not the button, you can use custom attribute on model to create and handle the button visibility.

add to your model:

```
public function getConfirmationButton()
{
   if ($data->appointment_status == 1) {
      return CHtml::button($this->appointment_status,array("onclick"=>"document.location.href=\'".Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("controller/action",array("id"=>$this->id))."\'"));
   } else {
      return '';
   }
}
```

and call it in your view:

```
..........
'link' => array(
        'header' => 'Confirmation',
        'type' => 'raw',
        'value' => '$data->confirmationButton',
    ),
...........
```

Answer (score 2):

you can use like this:

```
 $this->widget('zii.widgets.grid.CGridView', array(
    'id' => 'bookings-grid',
    'dataProvider' => $model->search(),
    'filter' => $model,
    'columns' => array(
        'id',
        'name',
        'email',
        'telephone',
        'time',
        'employee',
        'appointment_status',
        'client_ip',
        'link' => array(
            'header' => 'Confirmation',
            'type' => 'raw',
            'value' => function ($data) {
                if ($data->appointment_status == 1) {
                    return CHtml::button("$data->appointment_status", array("onclick" => "document.location.href=\'" . Yii::app()->controller->createUrl("controller/action", array("id" => $data->id)) . "\'"));
                } else {

                    return;
                }
            }
                ),
                array(
                    'class' => 'CButtonColumn',
                ),
            ),
        ));
```

Answer (score 1):

`visible` is a boolean or a PHP expression that will be evaluated to give a boolean. During the evaluation `$data` is assigned to the current item from the dataProvider used. `$data` doesn't exist outside of the evaluation function [`evaluateExpression()`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CComponent#evaluateExpression-detail). As such the implementation should be:

```
`visible` => '$data->appointment_status == 1',
```

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Now errors are not comming but sadly even when **appointment_status** equals 0 it shows the button

Answer (score 1):

You need to quote value of visible key in link array. So instead of this:

```
'visible'=>$data->appointment_status==1
```

It should be:

```
 'visible'=>'$data->appointment_status==1'
```

it should work now.

Comment: Thanks so much for the answer. Now errors are not comming but sadly even when **appointment_status** equals 0 it shows the button

Comment: Why don't you try to get more information on why it is not working. Hardcode true and false for visible and see if it will work. If it works then your problem is either in the expression or the way you written the column.

Comment: The way I written the column can't be wrong because it comes from CRUD.  And it works as it should when I add true or false...

Comment: Then if everything works your statement is not correct. Try somehow to var_dump it and see what you are getting. Also try this: '(($data->appointment_status == 1) ? true : false)'

Answer (score 1):

You will get undefined variable because `visible` not allow any callback.

Try this solution, it's yii2 code and i don't know much of Yii.

```
'delete' => function ($url, $model) {
                    return ($model->isVisible($model)) ? 
                    Html::a('<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-trash"></span>', 
                    $url, 
                    ['title' => Yii::t('app', 'Delete')]) : '';

public static function isVisible($data)
{
    return ($data->appointment_status == 1) ? true : false;
}
```